# Add text from UITextView to array?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

How would I go about adding each line of text in a UITextView to an array? I'd like to do this to allow users to make a list in a TextView and have random entries be pulled out of it later. I think I would need to parse the text in the TextView and sort by line, but I'm not exactly sure how to implement it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Implementation

```
let values = textView.text.componentsSeparatedByString("\n")
```

#### Example

```
var textViewText = "jkl \n def \n ghi \n abc"
let values = textViewText.componentsSeparatedByString("\n") // ["jkl ", " def ", " ghi ", " abc"]
```

If you want to sort, you can do that:

```
let sortedValues = values.sort { $0 < $1 } // [" abc", " def ", " ghi ", "jkl "]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to split the UITextView at each newline character. This can be done with the following code:

```
    let values = split(textView.text.characters) { $0 == "\n" } .map { String($0) }
```

You can also use the `sorted()` function to sort the string array if necessary:

```
    .sorted { $0 < $1 }
```

Answer (score -3):

```
NSMutableArray *array

array=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

- (IBAction)save:(id)sender
{ 
    NSString *string =UITextField.text;
    [array addObject:string];
}
```

Comment: Did you try this? That does not give the correct answer.